# Cancelling plpython runtime in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL function that wraps around a plpython3u function.

Now everytime I run that function and want to cancel it mid running, the function only stops running once the Python function finishes, which defeats the whole purpose of cancelling. This is especially problematic if the Python function goes into a never ending loops.

Is there a way to force cancellation on the python function, or any setup that makes it listen to the cancellation command?

(I'm using DBeaver)

Thank you.